# Sharepoint online - how to enable preview of Outlook emails?

Tags: email, sharepoint, outlook, sharepoint-online

The issue: we have a Document Library which is used for storing emails.
They are frequently viewed and constant download/open with Outlook takes a lot of extra time. We want to make them openable in browser or at least to be available for preview (like Word, Excel, PDF).

In SharePoint Server/Foundation this can achieved by altering Web Application Setting (Browser File Handling) but SharePoint Online lacks such configuration.

Do you know about any OOTB solution or JavaScript library that can help with that?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there are no OOTB solutions or JavaScript libraries to help out.

There is a 3rd party tool that offers this capability. SLIM Companion is a browser-based tool that mimics SharePoint as Windows Explorer. It uses the standard functionality from Outlook to create msg files; when users upload msg files it automatically extracts email metadata and populates the corresponding SharePoint columns. Users can drag emails from Outlook to the desktop and then to SharePoint and the metadata is extracted. SLIM Companion previews msg files in SharePoint without opening Outlook, displaying it in the browser. Attachments can be opened directly without first downloading the msg file in Outlook. SLIM Companion consists of a single 200 kB html file and does not require any software installs on SharePoint or the user's computer. See https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/outlook-sharepoint-integration-using-browser-paul-h-k-de-jong or www.slimapplications.com for further details.

Paul de Jong | SLIM Applications